# Prove that if $(x+y)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{xy}$, then $x = y$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x,y$ be integers. Prove that if $(x+y)^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{xy}$, then $x = \pm y$.

The given condition is equivalent to $x^2+y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{xy}$. How do we continue from here to prove that $x = \pm y$?

Answer (score 7):

$$ x^2 + y^2 = kxy  $$
$$ x^2 - k xy + y^2 = 0. $$
Divide by $y^2,$ let $r = x/y.$
$$ r^2 - kr + 1 = 0 $$
Discriminant is
$$ k^2 - 4. $$
Thi is not a square unless $k = \pm 2$

Comment: and then $(r\pm 1)^2 = 0\implies \frac{x}{y}=\pm 1 \implies x=\pm y\quad$ Sorry, OCD.

Comment: @mrnovice you got the letters wrong, they say QED

Comment: I was referring to my obsessive compulsive disorder lol.

Answer (score 5):

$$x^2 + y^2 = kxy$$

Let $d =gcd(x,y)$.  Then $x=da, y=db$ for some relatively prime $a,b$.

The equation becomes 
$$a^2+b^2=kab $$
with gcd$(a,b)=1$. This implies $a=\pm 1$ and $b=\pm1$. Indeed, if $a$ or $b$ are not $\pm1$, then $a$ or $b$ is divisible by a prime $p$. Then the prime $p$ also divides $kab$ and hence divides both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime, write $x=p^au, y=p^bv$ where $u,v$ are relatively prime with $p$. $xy=p^{a+b}uv$. Suppose $a<b$ If $xy$ divides $x^2+y^2=p^{2a}u^2+p^{2b}v^2$, we have ${{p^{2a}u^2+p^{2b}v^2}\over{p^{a+b}}}$ is an integer. This implies that $p^{a+b}$ divides $p^{2a}u^2$. This is impossible. We deduce that $a\geq b$ and similarly$b\geq a$. This implies that $x=y$ or $x=-y$.